# About definition of limit point

Tags: real-analysis

Definition: Let $X$ be a metric space. A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q\ne p$ such that $q \in E$.

What is so special about the limit point? How do we choose limit point?

Comment: a set $E$ could have lots of limit points; limit point of $E\subseteq\mathbb R$ means, for all $\epsilon$, $ E\cap(p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon)\setminus \{p\}$ is not empty

Comment: Be careful that you're not thinking "limit point" (of a set) is the same thing as "limit" (of a sequence or function). This is a definition of a separate concept, and trying to reconcile it with the definition of "limit" is a pitfall for confusion.

Comment: Theorem: A set $E$ in a metric space is closed if and only if $E$ contains its limit points

Comment: What do you mean by "I know limit point means (p−ϵ,p+ϵ)"?  That statement doesn't actually make any sense.  And what do you mean "choose limit points"? Points either are or are not limit points.  There is no choice involved?  A limit point can be thought of intuitively as a point that is "infinitely close" to other points in the set.  An example would be the set $(0,1)$.  $1$ is a limit point because every open interval $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon$) around $1$ will have points of $(0,1)$ in it. (for example ever point $y:1-\epsilon<y<1$ is in that neighborhood.)

Comment: We can only choose some $\varepsilon$. $(p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon)$ is a neighbourhood. Also, if you want $\varepsilon$ use `\varepsilon`.

Comment: A key thing to observe is that a limit point doesn't exist in isolation. It is defined relative to a set. One thing that's special about it is that the underlying set, relative to which it's defined, contains a subset of points which can get arbitrarily close to that point. Not all sets will have a limit point. And not all points in a set will be limit points. So it is special and distinct from other sets/points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limit point of $X$ is a point that is "arbitrarily close" to some points of $X$. For example, for any irrational number $p \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, we can approximate it arbitrarily well with some rational number $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Thus we say $p$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$ (with respect to the Euclidean metric).

Of course, a limit point does not have to be outside $X$; a point $x\in X$ can be "arbitrarily close" to other points in $X$. For example, if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and we use the Euclidean metric, then any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is also a limit point of $\mathbb{R}$ [1]. We call sets that contain all their limit points *closed*, and so for this reason $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. You can think of closed sets as those that don't have any "holes".

These examples should give you intuition as to why limit points are important: they are the points that are "arbitrarily close" to $X$, and understanding them lets us better understand $X$.

[1] Because given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$, we can pick $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-c| < \epsilon$. Namely, we can pick $c\in(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset \mathbb{R}$.